# How do I change the Python code to make it work properly

Tags: python, list, datetime, for-loop

I need some help.
I have a dictionary, which represents measured data during 8 days every 15 minutes, but some measurements are missing. Keys are datetime objects:

```
datetime(year, month, date, hour, minute)
```

and values represent measured parameter. My aim is to obtain a new dictionary with keys, which represent only time of day, e.g.:

```
time(hour, minute)
```

and its values are lists of measurements, which were provided at the same time every day. So, instead of the first dictionary of length L, I want to obtain new dictionary of length L/8 where every value is a list of 8 numbers (sometimes less, if there is a missing value at one or two days). It is very simple problem for me, if there are no missing values, but with missing values my program returns some strange result. If somebody can provide an idea, it would be great! Here is my code (tec is my initial dictionary):

```
time_of_day = []
date = datetime(2020, 1, 13, 0, 0)
while date < datetime(2020, 1, 14, 0, 0):
    time_of_day.append(date)
    date = date + td(minutes = 15)
day_tec = dict.fromkeys(time_of_day, [])
for i in day_tec.keys():
    j = 0
    while j < 8:
        try:
            day_tec[i].append(tec[i + j * timedelta(days = 1)])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
        j = j + 1

print(day_tec)
```

print(day_tec) returns dictionary with datetime objects as a keys from datetime(2020, 1, 13, 0, 0) to datetime(2020, 1, 14, 0, 0) every 15 minutes, but its values are lists with the same length as an initial dictionary length.

Comment: Show your code that produces the strange results and we should be able to help you fix it. But we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `defaultdict` to get what you want.  The code below will give you a dictionary where each key is a tuple of hour and minute, and each value is the recorded value in the `tec` `dict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict

day_tec = defaultdict(list)
for dt, value in tec.items():
    tm = (dt.hour, dt.minute)
    day_tec[tm].append(value)
print(day_tec)
```